# Create an mailing list of emails

Tags: lists, hyperlink, email

I am trying to create a mailing list for a list of emails for a PDF resource in which the user can either click on the individual or send to the entire group. I want this to be an online resource as well as a printable document any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Here is all I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{Random work type stuff}
\author{Joe Bloggs}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{}

 Send to the following distribution lists\\

%insert a link here

Bloggs, Joe (THE MAGIC KiNGDOM)
Joe.Bloggs@somewhere.net\\
\\
Bloggs2, Joe (THE MAGIC KiNGDOM)
Joe.Bloggs2@somewhere.net\\
\\
Bloggs3, Joe (THE MAGIC KiNGDOM)
Joe.Bloggs3@somewhere.net\\
\\
Bloggs4, Joe (THE MAGIC KiNGDOM)
Joe.Bloggs4@somewhere.net\\


\end{document}
```

Comment: I would link all email addresses with, e.g., `\href{mailto:Joe.Bloggs@somewhere.net}{` ... `}` and then place another link somewhere above or below with `\href{mailto:Joe.Bloggs@somewhere.net,Joe.Bloggs2@somewhere.net,` ... `}{` ... `}` .

Comment: Note that it is always better to send to multiple mail addresses using BCC, because otherwise everybody will get to know the email adresses of everybody else, which is maybe not intended (and bad practice from a privacy perspective). So, probably, something like `\href{mailto:myown@address.com?bcc=Joe.Bloggs@somewhere.net,Joe.Bloggs2@somewhere.net}{`...`}` is better ... But I am unsure what you really want to achieve here.